# Java looping through command line arguments to see what user inputs?

Tags: java, command, arguments, line, reverse

I've stumbled upon this question:

Write a complete Java program, command.java that prints out all its command line arguments in reverse order each on a separate line. It can have arbitrarily many command line arguments. For example, `java command az ba cad` would output

```
dac
ab
za
```

I'm not asking for spoonfeeding answers, but here are some thoughts I've figured out:

1) Reversing string can be done by StringBuilder once I've assigned every line into a String variable

However, the problem I've faced is whether I'm able to loop through the "command line" itself because it asks for "arbitrarily many command line", which means I'm not able to use a For loop because I do not know the range, but could I use a while loop? If so, how? Thank you.

Comment: I think u need to have look a [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)

Comment: No string building there. Argument are received as an array parameter to `main()`. Iterate the array backwards using a `for` loop, and print the values.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
     //here args array hold all the string inputs given from command line. you don't need 
     //worry how many were entered it will all be in the array. 
     // start printing the array from the last to first
     for(int i= args.length-1; i>=0; i++){
        System.out.println(args[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Use a `for` loop.

Comment: @Andreas thank you, I didn't know (String args[]) represents an array of input on command line. That makes it clearer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Command {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        for(int i= args.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
            input.append(args[i]);
            System.out.println(input.reverse());
        }
    }
}
```